# How to display random values in an array that are greater/less than the user's number? - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an integer array of 10 elements using a Random class and a loop to fill the array with numbers between 0 and 49. The program should then ask the user to provide a number between 0 and 49 and return this value in a separate method and then use another loop to review the array and display a message with every number in the array that is greater than the number provided by the user and every number in the array that is less than the number provided by the user.

What I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab7BTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Arrays
        int[] num = new int[30];
        int randomNumber;

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) {
            randomNumber = r.nextInt(50);
            System.out.println(num[x] + randomNumber);
        }
        int userNumber = getValue(num);
        getValue(num);

        System.out.println("Numbers higher than user's number include: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) {
            if (num[x] > userNumber) {
                System.out.println(num[x]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Numbers less than user's number include: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) {
            if (num[x] < userNumber) {
                System.out.println(num[x]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getValue(int[] num) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userNumber;
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 0 and 49: ");
        userNumber = kb.nextInt();

        return userNumber;

    }
}
```

I am confused on how to display the numbers greater than/less than the user's number in the output as the program isn't working as I intended it to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello and welcome! "the program isn't working as I intended it to work" please share how it's not working and how it should work instead, maybe [edit] your question and add input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: As far as I can see, your array is not initialized

Comment: Looks good, except that you forgot to fill the array in the first `for` loop. Just add `num[i] = randomNumber` and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done it right except the problem is that you haven't stored the random number in the Array `num[]`. All you need to do is assign the value of random number to the array. Also You have additionally called the function `getValue(num)` I have removed that as well.

> The line you need to append `num[x] = randomNumber;` inside the first for loop

Please use this

```
public static int getValue(int[] num) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userNumber;
    System.out.print("Enter a number between 0 and 49: ");
    userNumber = kb.nextInt();

    return userNumber;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] num = new int[30];
    int randomNumber;

    Random r = new Random();

    for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) {
        randomNumber = r.nextInt(50);
        num[x] = randomNumber;
        System.out.println(num[x] + randomNumber);
    }
    int userNumber = getValue(num);
    System.out.println(userNumber);

    System.out.println("Numbers higher than user's number include: ");
    for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) {
        if (num[x] > userNumber) {
            System.out.println(num[x]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Numbers less than user's number include: ");
    for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) {
        if (num[x] < userNumber) {
            System.out.println(num[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

> Input given after running the program : 10

Output:

```
Numbers higher than user's number include: 
35
43
17
40
47
13
20
44
22
16
27
21
32
32
37
18
45
13
46
18
46
Numbers less than user's number include: 
1
6
9
5
0
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize your array.From what I understand you try to add random number to uninitialized array element. So it may work if you change it like that:

```
for(int x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
      {
      randomNumber = r.nextInt(50);
      //System.out.println(num[x] + randomNumber);
      num[x]=randomnumber;
      }
```

And here you call the method twice so it took two input from user:

```
      int userNumber = getValue(num);
      getValue(num); --> I think you need to delete this.
```

Other than that it looks okay to me.